# Convert IP Range to IP address

Tags: bash

I have a raw file with IP ranges (xx.xx.xx.**xx**-yy.yy.yy.**yy**)
I want to create a new list with the range converted into single IP addresses.
(All ranges are in a 1-255 range)

*conditions*

(1) If the difference between the fourth IP octet on each line is less or equal to the max
    variable (say 5) It will loop and report each iteration as a single /32 address.

(2) IP address with more than the max variable will be reported as ip address with /24

The following bash script works fine but it is slow on files of 50,000 lines?
Any help would be appreciated. Its part of a script that does other functions so I need to stay in BASH.

```
for i in $data; do

    A=$(echo $i | sed 's/-.*//'); B=$(echo $i | sed 's/^.*-//')
    A1=$(echo $A | cut -d '.' -f 4); B1=$(echo $B | cut -d '.' -f 4)
    diff=`expr $B1 - $A1`

    if [ "$diff" == "0" ]; then
            echo $A >> $outfile
    elif [ "$diff" -gt "0" -a "$diff" -le $max ]; then
            echo $A >> $outfile
            for a in $(jot "$diff"); do
                    count=`expr $A1 + $a`
                    echo $A | sed "s/\.[0-9]*$/.$count/" >> $outfile
            done
    else
            echo $A | sed 's/\.[0-9]*$/.0\/24/' >> $outfile
    fi
done
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a language that already has a library to manipulate ipv4 addresses. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Glenn, how would you approach this is "perl". I could call a short perl script from this bash script.

Comment: a quick search on CPAN for "ip address range" reveals https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IPAddress::Util::Range which looks like it does what you want.

Comment: Convert the IP addresses to integers, `$network = $ip % 256;`, and it all becomes magical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely reason your script is so slow for 50000 lines is that you having `bash` call a lot of external programs (`sed`, `cut`, `jot`, `expr`), several times in each iteration of your inner and outer loops.  Forking external processes adds a lot of time overhead, when compounded over multiple iterations.

If you want to do this in bash, and improve performance, you'll need to make use of the equivalent features that are built into bash.  I took a stab at this for your script and came up with this.  I have tried to keep the functionality the same:

```
for i in $data; do

    A="${i%-*}"; B="${i#*-}"
    A1="${A##*.}"; B1="${B##*.}"
    diff=$(($B1 - $A1))

    if [ "$diff" == "0" ]; then
            echo $A >> $outfile
    elif [ "$diff" -gt "0" -a "$diff" -le $max ]; then
            echo $A >> $outfile
            for ((a=1; a<=$diff; a++)); do
                    count=$(($A1 + $a))
                    echo "${A%.*}.$count" >> $outfile
            done
    else
            echo "${A%.*}.0/24" >> $outfile
    fi
done
```

In particular I've made a lot of use of [parameter expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [arithmetic expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion).  I'd be interested to see what kind of speedup (if any) this has over the original.  I think it should be significantly faster.

Comment: wow. From 5 mins to 5 seconds. Thanks a lot! I had to use the Jot command as the 2nd "for loop" doesn't work in sh. Its a pfSense Freebsd Box.

Comment: I guess you could replace the `for $(jot)` with a while loop and manually increment the counter.  But I'm happy with a 60x speedup.  Upvotes will be graciously accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using python, install (download, extract and run `sudo python setup.py install`) ipaddr library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddr, then write something like this

```
import ipaddr
for ip in (ipaddr.IPv4Network('192.0.2.0/24')):
    print ip
```