# Bourne shell - convert IP range into set of subnets

Tags: function, ip, range, sh, cidr

I'm looking for a function in Bourne shell to convert a given range of IPs in the format "sIP-dIP" into a usable set of subnets that defines the very same range.
What I'm looking for precisely it's the very same result of the **IP Range** function provided at this site: http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr

example:

Given:

```
10.0.0.6-10.10.1.34:
```

Result:

```
10.0.0.6/31
10.0.0.8/29
10.0.0.16/28
10.0.0.32/27
10.0.0.64/26
10.0.0.128/25
10.0.1.0/24
10.0.2.0/23
10.0.4.0/22
10.0.8.0/21
10.0.16.0/20
10.0.32.0/19
10.0.64.0/18
10.0.128.0/17
10.1.0.0/16
10.2.0.0/15
10.4.0.0/14
10.8.0.0/15
10.10.0.0/24
10.10.1.0/27
10.10.1.32/31
10.10.1.34/32
```

I have seen many examples around but they are all for **bash**, **C** or **phyton**, but I'm on busybox with Bourne shell.

Can anybody please provide some inputs?

Many thanks!

Comment: I suggest trying to convert the `bash` solution you found to `sh`, and come back with any specific questions you have.

Comment: Ok, based on this bash script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699906/convert-ip-range-to-ip-address/22701994#22701994

I think the sh doesn't like
for ((a=1; a<=$diff; a++)); do

Comment: This is also an option but would require a conversion from php:
http://pastebin.com/VT1B0gDM

Comment: Ok, looking at that bash script without actually running it, I think that for loop is the only thing that needs to be replaced. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `bash`-specific C-style `for` loop with

```
a=1
while [ "$a" -le "$diff" ]; do
    # body of loop here
    a=$((a+1))
done
```

for POSIX compatibility.